# Relationship one to many with Flutter/Sqlite

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart

What is the best way to work with relationships one to many with Flutter/Sqlite?

Example: My class "Order" has a list of objects "Order Items" and one object Customer associated.

My difficulty is to understand how to write/retrieve the data since in my class I have objects and lists of associated objects.

I found Moor, but as I am studying, I wanted to know the concept behind, only with Flutter/Sqlite, to then use some more robust solution, because I believe that this way I will evolve more in my studies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 2 tables(simplest way).

```
Order
--------------------------
user_id   |   Order_id
--------------------------
   123    |    2
    


Order Items
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Order_id |   item_id   |  title           
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
   2     |    123      | 'title 1'
   2     |    123      | 'title 2'     
   2     |    34       | 'title 3'
```

Comment: Yes, I have two tables, my question is how save the objects of my class in this tables with the relationship. Exists some manner that work like objects to save?

Comment: sqlite is not orm, so you should save all the properties of class with a simple INSERT query.

Comment: Ok, the two answers help me. Is very difficult find examples with one to many relationship using Dart/Flutter and Sqlite!

Comment: I dont know what is the difficulty you have tables with columns and just need pass the parameters to save it, best way is trying to write it.